# Поиск в тексте адресов электронной почты и их частичное скрытие символами

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Программа должна находить в введённом тексте адреса электронной почты и частично скрывать в них(с помощью символа #) имя пользователя так, чтобы отображались только первый и последний символ, в то время как имя домена должно быть сохранено.
Не нужно внедрять стандарты RFC. Допустим, что символы электронной почты ограничены следующим набором: az, AZ, 0-9,., _, -, +, а первый и последний символы имени пользователя/домена должны быть az, AZ или 0-9.

Пример:

Ввод: default.user@gmail.com

Вывод:d##########r@gmail.com

Ввод: Sample text defaultuser@abc.edu.co.uk am

Вывод: Sample text d#########r@abc.edu.co.uk am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регулярное выражение: `[\w.+-]([\w.+-]*)[\w.+-]@[\w-]+[.\w-]+`

***Пример:***

```
import re


mail = r'Sample text defaultuser@abc.edu.co.uk am stack-L0v3R+@over.gh.РФ some'

mailParts = re.findall(r'[\w.+-]([\w.+-]*)[\w.+-]@[\w-]+[.\w-]+', mail)
for mailPart in mailParts:
    mail = mail.replace(mailPart, '#' * len(mailPart))

print(mail)
```

stdout:

```html
Sample text d#########r@abc.edu.co.uk am s##########+@over.gh.РФ some
```

*Примечания:*
*1) Регулярное выражение определяет почту, у которой минимум 2 символа в имени ящика. В Вашем случае, это неважно, но сказать стоило.*
*2) Возможна ошибка, если заменяемая часть почты будет где-либо ещё в строке. Сейчас стараюсь решить эту проблему.*

***P. S.:***
Прошу заметить, что это проверка не по RFC. Собственно, как Вы и просили. Она будет работать в большинстве случаев, но на *особо экзотических* вариациях вполне могут быть сбои.